# Mongoose collection design

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

This is probably going to get downvoted off of here but Im having a hard time wrapping my head around this issue.

In my Mongoose Schema I have a list of groups. These groups will be people, they will have an _id of that person, or if they dont have an _id they be listed by their email.

It makes sense to me to use `groups` so I can loop through a list without having to hardcode the list names, reason being is that I would like to let users add thier own groups. What I am not understanding is....

1) How can I allow the users to add to this collection, can I just do `groups.push(groupName)`? Wont Mongoose kick it back out? Also how does it know that I want Ids, name, email in the other field of collection.

2) I need to display the names of the groups, then separately the individuals in the group. I dont think I can show the keys in this fashion. So how can I display the names of the groups.

I think Im doing this fundamentally wrong but I cant figure out the right way

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
      bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/familySite");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type:String, required: true, unique: true},
    email: {type: String, required: false, unique: false},
    password: { type: String, required: true},
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,
    profile: {picture: String, nickname: String},
    permission:{app: Number}, //This will tell the app what level, 0 for Admin, 1 for User
    name: {
        first:String,
        middle:String,
        last:String,
        other: {
            startDate: Date,
            endDate: Date,
            first: String,
            middle: String,
            last: String
        }
    },
    lastName: String,
    address: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    zipCode: Number,
    phone: Number,
    birthday: Date,
    birthplace: String,
    userCover: String,
    categories: Array,
    defaultPermission: Number,
    events: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Event"
    }],
    moments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Moments"
    }],
    instants: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Instant"
    }],
    groups:
        [{family:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"},
            groupName: String,
            name: String,
            email: String
        },
         {friends:{
             type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
             ref: "User"},
             name: String,
             email: String,
             groupName: String,
         },
        {colleagues:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
            name: String,
            email: String,
            groupName: String,
        }
        }],
    likedMoments: [{ //This is for what this person likes, so they can refer later
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Moments"
    }],
    likedEvents: [{  //This is for what this person likes, so they can refer later
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Event"
    }],
    favoriteEvents: [{ //This is for personal events that are favorited
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Event"
    }],
    favoriteMoments: [{  //This is for personal moments that are favorited
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Moments"
    }]


})

//  I THINK I NEED TO MAKE THIS A METHOD SO I CAN GET IT ALL INTO APP.JS
// This uses bcrypt to hash passwords

userSchema.pre('save', function (next){
    var user = this;
    var SALT_FACTOR = 5;

    if(!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_FACTOR, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt,null, function (err, hash){
            if(err) return next(err);
            user.password - hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};



userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
```

Comment: Could you please post the entire schema model so it's easier to grasp the entire structure you're attempting. Also, is there anything you've tried in terms of mongoose methods, Create, Update etc. ?

Comment: I havent tried it yet, I'm just looking for the best way to handle this. I'll update it with the entire model.

Comment: @MathiasW the schema is posted